# How to replace white pages in CodeIgniter production mode with custom sites

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling

In CodeIgniter's production mode the user doesn't see any error messages. And this is exactly what I want. I want that if there are database errors or whatever the visitors shouldn't see the error message, but they also shouldn't see a white page, because this happens in production mode.

Is there any way to prevent this to happen and replace this white pages with an error page like 404 or similar things?

I hope you may understand my question and I didn't explained it too bad!

Answer (score 0):

You must turn debug off for database in config/database.php ->

```
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
```

It is better for your website security.

Comment: It makes the same thing as the production mode. My problem is that the page is completly blank in the production mode and I want to prevent that.